# Good lossless compression algorithm for small amount of data?

Tags: cuda, compression, gpgpu

I'm looking for a good lossless compression algorithm that can very quickly compress/decompress small amounts of data such as 256 floats that are between 0 and 1. I know RLE but maybe there's something better.

The background is that I'm working on volumetric data (e.g. 384³ floats) with CUDA and instead of storing the volume explicitly I want to divide it up into 8x8x4 sized blocks and store the compressed blocks. The CUDA kernels (each block consisting of 8x8x4 threads) the decompress the corresponding block, work on it and compress it again.

I'm grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: 384^3 floats is only about 226Mb of data. Why bother compressing such a small data set?

Comment: To reduce the amount of global memory accesses and ideally I would like to work on something like 1024³. Also, in some cases there are actually 5-6 floats per voxel so it would be about ~1Gb of data already on 384³.

Comment: Cuda also supports 16 bit floating point values, if you can pack half floats into a 32 bit type, you can get an effective doubling of memory throughout for far less computational expense than a lossless compression scheme would incur.

Answer (score 3):

A good lossless algorithm depends on the type of `float` quantities you have.
For `float` between 0 and 1, you may have almost the same exponent subvalue.
You know a `float` is a sign, a mantissa and a exponent.
If they are all >0, sign is always the same, do not store it.

Packing exponents together can be good; in that way you only have to store mantissae after.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to sort the numbers, then store them as a position and a difference. You can pack them together into as many bits as you need. The difference can be coded as a fraction where you only store the denominator.